.NET 8 Single file publishing does not copy certain files
I am migrating my C# WPF project to .NET 8 and trying to set up single-file deployment using VS2022. I need a bunch of resources lying next to the .exe file, so I set them up as
<None Update="data\Photo1.png">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="data\Photo2.png">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="data\Photo3.png">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="data\Video.mp4">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>

With PublishSingleFile being off it deploys perfectly. But with it being on some files just randomly refuse to deploy. For example, my source data folder looks like this:

And deployed data folder like this:

And I can't even find any reason why some files are being deployed and the other ones don't. I spent like 2 days dealing with this problem and tried everything I could think of and find in the internet. I tried:

Reviewing my .csproj file, but the only place where these filenames are mentioned are in the code above and I couldn't find anything that can prevent deployment of any files in general;
Reviewing the .pubxml file, but it does not contain anything related to specific files;
Setting Build action to Content;
Deleting the whole deployment folder and publishing again, cleaning the solution, restarting VS, deleting .vs folder, etc.;
Checking permissions for these files - they are exactly the same;
Creating a new project and deploying the same 4 files from it - it works perfectly fine.

But the interesting thing though is that if I replace Photo1.png with a copy of Photo2.png - it starts deploying it without any change to the project! The fact that it treats the file by it's content, not filename makes no sense and makes me think that it might be some kind of a VS bug.
Any suggestions what else can I try or check in my project files?
